# What am I doing wrong here while trying to set up Forge for Minecraft mods?

Tags: cmd, minecraft-forge

```
gradlew setupDecompWorkspace
This mapping 'snapshot_20160518' was designed for MC 1.9.4! Use at your own peril.
```

#

```
     ForgeGradle 2.2-SNAPSHOT-c438b06
```

https://github.com/MinecraftForge/ForgeGradle

#

```
           Powered by MCP unknown
         http://modcoderpack.com
     by: Searge, ProfMobius, Fesh0r,
     R4wk, ZeuX, IngisKahn, bspkrs
```

#

```
:deobfCompileDummyTask
:deobfProvidedDummyTask
:getVersionJson
:extractUserdev UP-TO-DATE
:extractDependencyATs SKIPPED
:extractMcpData SKIPPED
:extractMcpMappings SKIPPED
:genSrgs SKIPPED
:downloadClient SKIPPED
:downloadServer SKIPPED
:splitServerJar SKIPPED
:mergeJars SKIPPED
:deobfMcSRG SKIPPED
:decompileMc FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':decompileMc'.
> Java heap space

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 36.311 secs
```

Any help with fixing this error? I got this suggestion from a different page, but I need a little bit more then the unspecific instructions here:

"In case you will receive an error while running the task :decompileMC ( the fourth step )

Execution failed for task ':decompileMc'.
GC overhead limit exceeded

assign more RAM into gradle by adding org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2G into the file ~/.gradle/gradle.properties (create file if doesn’t exist)."

Please take into consideration that I have very limited knowledge of CMD and a mild knowledge of java as I am just starting out in this 'coding' thing. Cheers for the responses that come!

Answer (score 1):

are you on linux?
if then type

> cd $home/.gradle

then

> pico gradle.properties

type in it

> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2G

CTRL + X to save

then try again.

Your java process simply needs more ram assigned than it gets default.

Comment: then look in the same directory for a .gradle directory where your .minecraft dir is located normally, and create the text file with notepad. It might even be in your home directory, if you go to your user home. C:\users\PolishPastry